# Store variable using sessions

Tags: javascript, php, session-variables

I have a variable which is updated on every page shift, but I want to store the value in the first call for good somehow.

The variable is e.g

```
   $sizeOfSearch = $value['HotelList']['@activePropertyCount'];
```

First time the page loads it's 933, on next page the same value is retrieved but it's now different e.g 845. This goes on page for page.

What I want is to store 933 for good. So I can show this number on every page.

Can I somehow store the first time this value is retrieved ? (I get the value via REST request)

Sessions maybe or ?

Comment: "for good" is how long? sessions don't last forever and are per visitor specific. reads more like you want to store a number in a db\file and echo on every page (or store it hard codded in the html)

Comment: just add session_start of the two for the first page , you'll find it still there until world ends Lolz

Comment: I only want to store it for as long as the visitor is active on the page. So not for long - and it needs to be dynamic in the sence that the first value retrieved is different for each user - as each user make different searches

Comment: ok, well yes then sessions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`session_start()` creates a session or resumes the current one based on a session identifier passed via a GET or POST request, or passed via a cookie.

When `session_start()` is called or when a session auto starts, PHP will call the open and read session save handlers. These will either be a built-in save handler provided by default or by PHP extensions (such as SQLite or Memcached); or can be custom handler as defined by `session_set_save_handler()`. The read callback will retrieve any existing session data (stored in a special serialized format) and will be unserialized and used to automatically populate the `$_SESSION` superglobal when the read callback returns the saved session data back to PHP session handling.

So, on every page make sure to start it with:

```
<?php
session_start();
```

Then, you set the value like this:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['name'])) {
    $_SESSION['name'] = $sizeOfSearch;
}
```

Whenever you need the retrieve the value use this:

```
print $_SESSION['name'];
```

This session will keep store the variable as long as you don't destroy it. Code for destroying a session:

```
session_destroy();
```

Comment: But when I set value like this : $_SESSION['name'] = $sizeOfSearch; The value is still changing on each page. How can that be if it should store the first time only? @Lea Tano

Comment: @TroelsJohannesen I just edited it. This will only set it the first time (until session expired)

Comment: Then you need session_destroy(); then activate other session to start again

Comment: @TroelsJohannesen - Do not misunderstand. The `$_SESSION` variable is just a variable like any other. It is stored on (by) the server, not by the browser. Nothing at all unusual about how it works **except** the need to put `session_start()` at top of every page. If the value is changing, it's just a normal variable -- find out why.

Comment: Thanks @JeanGkol great comment. if you don't mind I will include it in the answer. so we can have all the actions

Comment: Note: If you specify `session_start()` twice on the same page -- usually because it is also at the top of an include file -- you will get errors. However, this format will avoid those errors: `if (!session_id()) session_start();`

Comment: @TroelsJohannesen Pls watch lang. Reduce your problem -- take ten mins and do some tests with the $_SESSION variable. Observe how it can save the variable contents between 2 or 3 pages. Take the time to do this.

Comment: In addition, I recommend you to try to learn how to use `xdebug` with breakpoints. Use a real IDE like phpStorm (it can be any other IDE) and if this project does not have any due day (like a job or school) enjoy fixing issues. It is when you learn most.

Comment: Got it now! :) I didn't realize that you had to start the session at the very very top. Had it inside header.php

Comment: that is why I said >So, on every page make sure to start it with: