# Form won't forward $score to next page

Tags: php, forms, session

When a user takes a quiz, their score is captured in the value $grade, which displays fine on the quiz's home page. But if I change the form action to forward the user to a new page (grade.php), $grade loses its value.

How can I capture the value and display it on the next page? The values for PreviousURL and user_token display...

```
<form action="grade.php" method="post" id="quiz">
  <input type="hidden" name="PreviousURL" id="url" />
  <input type="hidden" name="user_token" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['user_token']; ?>" />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit Quiz" />
</form>
```

So I tried this, but it doesn't work...

```
  <input type="hidden" name="grade" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['grade'] ?>" />
```

Comment: the code you use to get the value of $grade in quiz home page now after change the action use this same code in grade.php then echo the value of $grade i hope now you get this if not then show me the code

Comment: Good tip. I just deleted the code with the answer key and scoring script from the quiz' home page and pasted it on the page users are forwarded to (grade.php). It works! ;)

Comment: it is the login not the tio form action means where you submit all these variable value when you do action in home page it work fine because you submit these values in home page and print it in grade page but when you do this in grade you can submit from but cannot get the new values

Answer (score 0):

You should not save form values in `$_SESSION` as form values are already in $_POST superglobal.

You can do it like

```
<form action="grade.php" method="post" id="quiz">
  <input type="hidden" name="PreviousURL" id="url" />
  <input type="hidden" name="user_token" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['user_token']) ? $_POST['user_token'] : '' ; ?>" />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit Quiz" />
</form>
```

So basically it test if there is a value in user_token field it will apply that value other wise it will set to '' (nothing). If you are not familiar with the ternary operator syntax please refer to http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Updated Part:

```
// Your form page goes like 
<?php session_start();
      print_r($_SESSION); // If there is a session your form should show the value of user_token

// Rest of the script + html


?>

// grade.php
<?php session_start();
// do a print_r to see if you are receving session variables by
print_r($_SESSION);
```

Comment: Raheel, I edited my code as you suggested, but now it doesn't display a value for user_token, even if I'm logged in...  ["user_token"]=> string(0)

Comment: I think i got your question wrong. Can you please put the php part of your question. I guess you have saved your user_token in session before the form post. So in that case all you need to do is to place `session_start()` both in grade.php as well as on the page where your form is located. Make sure you place `session_start` on the very first line of script on both pages.

Comment: OK, I think I understand now. Sorry for the confusion; I should have mentioned that I wasn't logged in when I first tested the quiz.

Answer (score 0):

on `grade.php` make sure to start the file with

```
session_start();
```

Based on your question, I assume that you did not start the session on `grade.php`. There is not much information about the file

If you don't start the session the values of `$_SESSION` get destroyed

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I'm just learning how to work with sessions, and I should have mentioned that I wasn't even logged in when I answered the questions and clicked the Submit button. I don't understand why it even displays a value for user_token; I thought you had to be logged in to get that value.

Comment: I can not assume how your code works, since I don't have a complete code. But you can initialize a session any time you want. This is an answer to a question that I wrote  couple weeks ago bout sessions. It might help you to understand sessions

Comment: I forgot the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28665244/store-variable-using-sessions/28665283#28665283